# input box placeholder being overwritten

Tags: html, css

I have an input box on a page:

```
<label>Email Address<input type="email" placeholder="asdf" name="email" /></label>
```

when I load the page, this placeholder is being overwritten with the text

**`Enter your email here`**

and I cannot figure out where this is coming from.  Whether I have a placeholder or not, the text comes into the box on page load, and I don't want it to.  Whether I set the input type to `text` or `email` it still does this.  It's only this ONE box on the page that auto-fills this text, and I have no idea where it's coming from.  I've looked in the developer console to see whether it may be a css issue, but I can't see anything that would be causing this to pre-populate with a message:

```
.addForm input[type="text"] {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: 900;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px;        
    border: 1px solid #FDC;
    background-color : #E8E8E7;
    box-shadow: 6px 4px 4px -4px rgba(77,89,85,0.36);
}
```

any ideas?

## Update

It seems to be coming from my `<label>` having the word "email" inside of it.  How frustrating!  If I remove the word `email` or `e-mail`, the text no longer appears.  What causes this and how do I stop it?

Here's a jfiddle with the relevant html/css

https://jsfiddle.net/9ut5ksto/

Comment: Do you maybe have autocomplete on or do you have any other scripts or something on your page?

Comment: you should most likely create a jsfiddle to show this. Since this sounds like autocomplete or some hidden js you did not notice.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but incomplete without the code. Also, info on the browser would be interesting, in case it's browser-specific. Does it happen on all of them?

Comment: Okay, updated with jfiddle - I'm running in Chrome.  Setting the form to `autocomplete=off` doesn't fix this.

Comment: did not change the placeholder in chrome... maybe you really have installed plugins, which will do this

Comment: You are correct.......... my work had an auto-fill extension installed.... I didn't check that.  Thanks :)